# how do I install exactly environment.yaml to base environment (anaconda)

Tags: anaconda, conda

I initially setup my base environment with

```
conda env update --file environment.yaml --prune
```

However, I did some bad updates using pip. Now my environment breaks.

How do I revert back exactly to `environment.yaml`. The same command does not work, since it thought everything is updated. I want the environment exactly the same as environment.yaml which means downgrade some packages if current version is more advanced. And also remove the packages if it is not shown in environment.yaml.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?